# Configure AutoMapper in .NET CORE 2.2 Web API App

Tags: automapper, asp.net-core-2.2, webapi

I have configured AutoMapper 'AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection Version 7.0'in my Web API application as following; I get the Missing Type Map configuration Mapping error.

### Startup

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddDbContext<SupplierContext>(options =>
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyDatabase"));

        services.AddTransient<IAppService, AppService>();

        var profiles = from type in typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetTypes()
                       where typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                       select (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        var mapConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var profile in profiles)
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(profile);
            }
        });

        var mapper = mapConfig.CreateMapper();

        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
    }
```

I have created a profile in main project API under the folder

profile

```
 public UserProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDataView>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(dataModel => dataModel.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom(dataModel => dataModel.Title))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(dataModel => dataModel.FirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(dataModel => dataModel.LastName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ActivationDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(dataModel => dataModel.ActivationDate));

        //CreateMap<User, UserDataView>()
        //    .ReverseMap();

    }
```

### User class

```
public class User
{
  
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime ActivationDate { get; set; }

}
```

When I try to map model data to Dto, I get missing type map configuration error

### Error

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

 Mapping types:
 Task`1 -> List`1
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyApp.Model.User.User, MyApp.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea70000]] -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyApp.Model.DTOs.UserDataView, MyApp.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

### Auto Mapping

```
 var UserDataModel = (from user in _context.Users
                   join email in _context.Emails on user.Id equals email.userId into se
                   join phone in _context.Phones on user.Id equals phone.userId into sp
                   select new User 
                   {
                       Id = user.Id,
                       Title = user.Title,
                       FirstName = user.FirstName,
                       LastName = user.LastName,
                       ActivationDate = user.ActivationDate,
                   }).ToListAsync();

var dataResult = _mapper.Map<List<UserDataView>>(UserDataModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake. The UserDataModel is of Type Task<List> where my profile class is expecting different.

I have changed my LINQ script as following and it did work

```
var UserDataModel = (from user in _context.Users
               join email in _context.Emails on user.Id equals email.userId into se
               join phone in _context.Phones on user.Id equals phone.userId into sp
               select new User 
               {
                   Id = user.Id,
                   Title = user.Title,
                   FirstName = user.FirstName,
                   LastName = user.LastName,
                   ActivationDate = user.ActivationDate,
               });

 var ddf = _mapper.Map<List<SupplierDataView>>(supplierDataModel);
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html